# Apply different functions to an array depending on the value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

I'm attempting to apply a different function to the first and second part of a numpy array. So in this example, multiplying the terms less than 0.5 by 2 and adding 1 to the terms of 0.5 and above.

```
def myFunc:
    x = numpy.linspace(0,1,11)
    def test():
        for i in x:
            if i < 0.5:
                a = i*2
            else:
                a = i+1.0
        return(a)

print(test())
```

Which I want to return:

```
[0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]
```

Thank You.

Comment: Look at `np.piecewise`.

Comment: You can also accept an answer. This will also make it more probable that your next question will be answered as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `numpy` solution , I will using `select`

```
np.select([x<0.5,x>=0.5],[x*2,x+1])
Out[905]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2. ])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
x[x<0.5]*=2
x[x>=0.5]+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a list comprehension:

```
[i*2 if i < 0.5 else i+1 for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
x[x < 0.5] *= 2
x[x >= 0.5] +=1
```

If you want to stick with `numpy`, this is highly preferable over list comprehensions.

Here is a short comparison using list comprehension and `numpy` masking:

```
def myFunc_lc(x):
    return np.asarray([i*2 if i < 0.5 else i+1 for i in x])

def myFunc_np(x):
    x[x < 0.5] *= 2
    x[x >= 0.5] +=1
    return x

def myFunc_np2(x):  # using a constant masking array
    ma = x < 0.5
    x[ma] *= 2
    x[~ma] +=1
    return x

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
%timeit myFunc_np(x)  # 6.62 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit myFunc_np2(x)  # 6.24 µs ± 113 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit myFunc_lc(x)  # 6.75 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.select([x<0.5,x>=0.5],[x*2,x+1])  # 39.9 µs ± 1.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10000)
%timeit myFunc_np(x)  # 43.4 µs ± 1.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit myFunc_np2(x)  # 43.8 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit myFunc_lc(x)  # 3.7 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.select([x<0.5,x>=0.5],[x*2,x+1])  # 79.2 µs ± 2.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I guess it is quite obvious why `numpy` masking is better than list comprehension. Especially when using larger arrays, `numpy` is alot faster.
Using small arrays, numpy is only slightly faster. `np.select` is really slow for short arrays but quite ok for larger arrays. Creating a mask in `myFunc_np2` is even faster for small arrays, but slightly slower for larger arrays.